# Lifting group actions on a gerbe

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C$ is a smooth projective curve, over a number field.
Let $G$ be its group of automorphisms. Suppose $\alpha$ is a class in $H^2(C,\mu_2)$ left fixed by $G$.
Let $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow C$ be a $\mu_2$-gerbe corresponding to $\alpha$.
Does the action of $G$ lift on $\mathcal{C}$.
If not, under what conditions does $G$-action lift on $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Can you remind us of the definition of an action of $G$ on $\mathcal{C}$?  In particular, is the associativity condition a cocycle condition on the $2$-morphism relating translation by $gh$ and the composition of translations by $g$ and $h$?